# Как быстрее перевести два байта в переменную типа unsigned short?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Есть массив unsigned char B[2], необходимо перевести эти два байта в переменную типа unsigned short, какой из описанных ниже алгоритмов справится с этим быстрей!?

1. `unsigned short A=B[0]+B[1]*255;`
2. `unsigned short A; CopyMemory (&A,B,2);`

И второй дополнительный вопрос - если потребуется преобразовать 8 байт в тип double, какой алгоритм победит?

Comment: uint16_t A = \*(uint16_t\*)&B[0]; ?

Comment: Круто, но не совсем понятно, и нет ответа на оба вопроса! :) И по моему &B[0]=B

Comment: Сонькин предложил самый быстрый вариант. Все просто. Сначала берем адрес B[0]. А затем мы интерпретируем значение в 2-х байтах как число типа uint16_t. Т.е. приводим к указателю, а затем разыменовываем.

Comment: Альтернативная запись: 
<pte>uint16_t A = *(uint16_t*)B;</pre>
По идее ведь B и &B[0] - одно и тоже.

Comment: <i>если потребуется преобразовать 8 байт в тип double!? Какой алгоритм победит?</i><p>
Расшифруйте что значит "преобразовать"? Просто интерпретировать какие байты как число double? Или перевести из целого 8 байтного по каким-то адресам в double по-честному?

Comment: Перевести 8 байт массива в переменную типа double!

Comment: Скорость обоих вариантов будет зависеть от платформы и реализации функции CopyMemory. На системах без аппаратного умножения или с ним, но долгим победит вариант копипасты. Если умножение шустрое, то непонятно. 

В первом варианте: достать B[1], умножить на 255, достать B[0], сложить, поместить в A. Мало операций. В копимемори - сколько-то съест цикл, если компилятор его не развернёт. Плюс копирование... Если оно не инлайн функция - то ещё пока со стёком он наиграется на входе и выходе. В общем фиг знает=)

Comment: Когда делаете такие преобразования - проще всего прямой копипастой памяти. Однако учтите, если вы это будете пихать в файл, то не факт, что оно потом прочитается так, как вы задумывали. Дабл - он не везде одинаковый...

Comment: Вы собираетесь оставить платформенно-зависимую дырку? Не во всех архитектурах младший байт идёт впереди...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
unsigned short A=B[0]+B[1]*255;
```

Сводится по сути к B[0]+B[1]<<8; Т.е. основное - две операции: сложение+сдвиг. И с умножением ошиблись - нужно умножать на 0x100, т.е. 256. Если переменная A сильно нужна - добавить пересылки в память. По факту - скорее всего переменная A оптимизируется и значение возьмется из регистра процессора.

```
unsigned short A; CopyMemory (&A,B,2);
```

Вызов ф-ции. Итого - организация стека (push/pop, настройка регистров, передача параметров), код самой ф-ции. Если функция встраиваемая - уже лучше, но по скорости все равно будет хуже, чем сложение+сдвиг, т.к. имеется работа с памятью. Оптимизировать не удастся.

```
uint16_t A = *(uint16_t*)&B[0];
```

и клоны. Всего лишь две пересылки (память -> регистр, регистр -> память). В лучшем случае соптимизируется и значение A далее опять же возьмется из регистра. Т.е. по факту - одно чтение из памяти. И никаких записей в память.

Вообще на самом деле надо брать и смотреть ассемблерный листинг. Сейчас все компиляторы оптимизирующие. И просто грубо преобразовывать однозначно одну инструкцию языка в одну или несколько инструкций процессора не будут. А будут подгадывать максимально эффективный вариант по одному из критериев. Их на самом деле два: скорость и размер. И для каждого процессора правила оптимизации свои.

Касательно double:

```
double A = *(double*)&B[0];
```

Но с даблом я бы поостерегся. Дело в том, что целые числа хранятся как целые, поразрядно. Каждый байт последовательно друг за другом. И запись

```
unsigned short A=B[0]+B[1]*256;
unsigned long  C=B[0]+B[1]<<8+B[2]<<16+B[3]<<24;
```

работает. А внутреннее представление double существенно сложнее. Мантисса, экспонента, знаки... Фу. бр. И просто выдрать из double определенные разряды сложнее.

Comment: И если вам не трудно, обьясните конструкцию этой строки:double A = *(double*)&B[0];   
double A - здесь всё ясно  
*(double*)&B[0] - умножить слева от скобки - разыминовывание тоже ясно, не ясно только чего   
(double*) - не совсем понятно  
&B[0] - адрес первого элемента массива

Comment: &B\[0\] - это адрес <s>нулевого</s> первого элемента массива B - т.е. по сути указатель<p>
(double\*)&B\[0\] - это мы привели указатель к типу double\*<p>
\*(double\*)&B\[0\] - а это мы разыменовали полученный указатель, т.е. получили значение числа типа double по адресу = адресу ячейки B[0]